# apt-get upgrade only those packages which are below 100MB in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

Say I want to upgrade all those packages in Ubuntu OS which are below 100 MB.

I need a command for that (in shell), looks like there is no standard command to do that in terminal.

There are multiple drivers which are above 100 MB and I don't want to upgrade them for the time being.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to upgrade all packages except for the select ones?

Comment: It would be better to filter packages according to the sizes. Say, I want to upgrade all packages within a size limit. There might be 100 packages which I don't want to upgrade (During download we can see the package size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Terminal, you can [query package size](https://linoxide.com/show-installed-package-size-ubuntu-debian/):

   `dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | tail -n 10`

   Pipe the output to build an update shell script.
2. You can also sort packages on size in Synaptic Package Manager:

   Then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click to select a range of packages (i.e., those less than 100kB), "Mark All [for] Upgrades" (The *S* field is status, showing those needing download), and apply the upgrade.

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

Comment: The 2nd option should work, but I need the command line version. Your point no. 1 filters the packages which I don't want to upgrade, how to pipe the command so that I can upgrade all the other packages except those?

Comment: @Jimut123, sorry, this site is not for writing scripts from scratch. You should be able to filter for those *less* than 100 kB, abstract the package name, concatenate that list with a statement to download that package, and save as a script. Yes, that is just a broad outline, but if you start on it and need help, come back with your statement.

Comment: Cool, I thought it would be about 1 line piped command. That command will help those who use ssh and terminal for their job. Thanks for the suggestions!